# What problems could happen if I replaced add_filter and add_action with the function calling

Tags: filters, actions

I'm new to WordPress, and to learn more about how to build WordPress themes, I'm now analyzing the code of a theme I downloaded and trying to make some changes in it.

Two of the built-in functions in WordPress are `add_filter` and `add_action`, and they both add something called **HOOK** to the functions.   So when the function `someFn` is called, all the functions that was HOOKED with the `someFn` functions are called after the finishing of the `someFn` calling.

My question is.

What will happen If I Just called the functions exactly before the closing bracket of the `someFn` function`someFn`(in the end of the function) instead of using `add_filter` and `add_action` (The 2 functions' code is exactlt the same).

Would that cause any problem to my code somehow?

I know that there are some functions (Like the `init` function) stored in the WordPress files and I shouldn't edit them.I'm just talking about hocking the theme functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly as your question is a bit scrambled

### BACKGROUND

Functions, just like your car, are pretty useless objects until they are put to use of some kind. Simply being defined in `functions.php` or in a plugin makes functions as useful as a car parked in a garage, it is there, but doing nothing useful at that given point in time.

That is where actions and filters come in. Your function can be hooked to some filter or action where it can perform a given duty, make it useful, it is like driving your car to work now, it became a useful object. (*Functions can alse be called directly into a template to make it useful*)

Hooks have specific tasks

- filters are meant to change the value of the variable passed as first argument in the callback function hooked to the filter
- actions are suppose to perform some kind of duty specified by the callback function, this can be anything which falls in scope of that action like a redirection to another page or changing query variables inside the `WP_Query` class

Hooks are not just used by core, but by plugins and themes as well. The main purpose of any hook in any scenario is to make something dynamic and editable without having to modify the given file directly. A theme, plugin or core can be altered by a custom plugin without having to directly change any piece of code. This ofcourse have huge benefits when it comes to updating core, themes and plugins

### THEME LEVEL FILTERS AND ACTIONS

To answer your question directly, you need to look at the following, are you creating a theme

- for yourself
- for public use

If you are creating a theme for yourself and have no intention of releasing it publicly, you can leave out the use of custom filters and actions.

Instead of using filters to filter the return value of a function or a variable, you can set the value to some desired static value. On the other hand, instead of using `do_action()` calls in your templates, you can just call the function where needed. So instead of doing the following in a template

```
do_action( 'some_action' );
```

and then in functions

```
add_action( 'some_action', 'some_function' );
function some_function()
{
    echo 'Some custom text';
}
```

you can simply just do the following in functions

```
function some_function()
{
    echo 'Some custom text';
}
```

and then call the function directly in your templates

```
some_function();
```

Even though you do not intend to release your theme publicly, it is still quite useful to make use of custom filters and action

If you intent to release a theme publicly, you would do users and child theme authors a huge favor to make values filterable and by making use of `do_action()` calls in order for them to unhook your function and then hook their own function to the action.

### NOTE

We all tend to make use of closures for convenience, but they have one huge drawback, they are almost non-removable as anonymous functions don't have callback names. For themes that will be released publicly, closures should be avoided accept if you don't want something to be removable. Instead of doing

```
add_action( 'some_action', function ()
{
    echo 'Some value'
}):
```

rather do

```
add_action( 'some_action', 'some_function' );
function some_function()
{
    echo 'Some value';
}
```

A child theme or a plugin can now remove `some_function()` from the action with `remove_action()` and then plug/hook his own custom function to the `some_action` action call. This cannot be done when using closures